# LspConfig code action does not work

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua, lsp

I have problems with LspConfig when extracting a method to a new file. When executing the following command `buf_set_keymap("n","<space>ca","<cmd> lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>", opts)` remove the method to move and create me the file with the name of was method, but I did not copy the method to that file before created.

This problem is presented to me with typescript

I'm going to share my lsp configuration with you, to give you a better understanding.

```
    local lsp_installer = require("nvim-lsp-installer")

-- Add additional capabilities supported by nvim-cmp
local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
capabilities = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").update_capabilities(capabilities)
-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  local function buf_set_keymap(...)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, ...)
  end
  local function buf_set_option(...)
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, ...)
  end

  -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  buf_set_option("omnifunc", "v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc")

  -- Mappings.
  local opts = {noremap = true, silent = true}

  -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
  buf_set_keymap("n", "gD", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "gd", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "K", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "gi", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<C-k>", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>wa", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>wr", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>wl", "<cmd>lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>D", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.type_definition()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>rn", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>ca", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "gr", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>e", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "[d", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "]d", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.goto_next()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>q", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.set_loclist()<CR>", opts)
  buf_set_keymap("n", "<space>f", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()<CR>", opts)
end

lsp_installer.on_server_ready(
  function(server)
    local opts = {
      on_attach = on_attach,
      capabilities = capabilities,
      flag = {
        debounce_text_changes = 150
      }
    }

    if server.name == "sumneko_lua" then
      opts.settings = {
        Lua = {
          diagnostics = {
            -- Get the language server to recognize the `vim` global
            globals = {"vim"}
          }
        }
      }
    end

    server:setup(opts)
  end
)

-- Set completeopt to have a better completion experience
vim.o.completeopt = "menuone,noselect"
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, but: try debugging the configuration [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604). Being highly specific to NeoVim + LSP, you might also have better luck in the spaces dedicated to those things.